# Как возратить набор картинок из контроллера flask

Tags: python, flask

Как возратить набор картинок из контроллера flask, пытаюсь пока что возратить одну, я так помимаю её нужно закодировать в base64, но получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код:

```
@app.route('/files', methods=['POST'])
def get_files():
    print(base64.b64encode(request.files['images'].read()))
    return str(base64.b64encode(request.files['images'].read()))
```

Comment: Ну, надо тип содержимого видимо как-то прописать. Насколько я помню, браузеры на него ориентируются. Вот пример кстати https://stackoverflow.com/a/8637217/8324991

Comment: @CrazyElf, а можно несколько вернуть массивом?

Comment: А получать вы их чем собираетесь? Если браузером, то как он вам массив картинок покажет? Это надо возвращать `html` где будут вписаны ссылки на картинки, а потом индивидуально эти картинки возвращать. А если это `API` у вас и запрос от скрипта, то, наверное, можно ещё как-то вернуть какой-то контейнер, но это надо разбираться тоже

Comment: @CrazyElf, у меня flask + react, у меня есть вот такой код: https://pastenow.ru/dbb4c8520191a4cd8c83c2bac338d857, но мне не надо импортировать картинки, я их достаю: files = request.files.getlist('images'), не подскажите как fileStorage перевести в двоичный код, чтобы потом прокинуть в base64.b64encode